# AngularJs ng-class using expression

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

Recently I have need to apply a class base on the json data from server side. But seems like it doesn't work out for me. Any idea about this? Thanks
code:

```
<tr>
    <td><span class=" text4 green col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-class="numclass('inProgressCounter')">{{inProgressCounter}}</span></td>
    <td><span class=" text4 green col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-class="numclass('inProgressCounter')">-Accounting Review</span></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.numclass = function(num){
    var classname='';
    if(num > 999)
    {
      classname = 'smalltext';
    }

    if(num <= 999){
        classname = 'defaulttext';
    }

    return classname;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why a function? I believe you can achieve the same thing using this:

```
<tag ng-class="{smalltext: inProgressCounter &gt; 999, defaulttext: inProgressCounter &lt;= 999}"></tag>
```

If you want to use a function, you don't need `ng-class`:

```
<tag class="foo bar {{numclass(inProgressCounter)}}"></tag>
```

Comment: isn't this sort of logic better suited to be in the controller?

Comment: although that does work isn't that a bit sloppy looking?

Comment: @mcranston18: it is a matter of taste, but if you want to do it on the controller, use the regular `class` attribute with an angular expression inside instead of the `ng-class` directive. @floor: I like to place presentation logic in the presentation layer and only business logic on the controller, but as I said it is a matter of taste.

Comment: why is it more suitable to use regular `class` in this instance? Isn't `ng-class` suitable to any dynamic class?

Comment: @mcranston18 `ng-class` works if the expression evaluates to a string containing space-delimited class names, an array of strings, or an object. I didn't say it is more suitable, I just said you don't really need `ng-class` for that simple use case.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But would you please tell me where is problem for my code? why it doesn't work? and for me ,usually I will put those code in my controller:)

Comment: Just a wide guess but perhaps you don't need to enclose the parameter in single quotes.